# How to remove next element using JavaScript (without using jQuery)

Tags: javascript, dom, removechild, appendchild, createelement

I need something like this.

```
<a onclick="SaveNote(this);" >Save</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="112">Cancel</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="112">Delete</a>
```

If I click on the `Save` anchor , I want to remove all three anchor elements as  shown above, without using any `id`, and replace them with an `Edit` anchor. I currently have some Javascript code that looks something like this :

```
function SaveNote(e){
   e.nextSibling.removeNode;
   e.nextSibling.removeNode;
   e.nextSibling.removeNode;
}
```

Have you any idea regarding this issue?

Comment: removeNode spelling is wrong and it should be removeNode() as it is a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this

HTML

```
<div>Stuff before</div>
<div>
    <a id="save" href="#">Save</a>
    <a id="cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
    <a id="delete" href="#">Delete</a>
</div>
<div>Stuff after</div>
```

Javascript

```
function emptyNode(node) {
    while (node.firstChild) {
        node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
    }
}

function saveNote(e) {
    var parent = e.target.parentNode,
        edit = document.createElement("a");

    emptyNode(parent);

    edit.id = "edit";
    edit.href = "#";
    edit.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Edit"));
    parent.appendChild(edit);
}

document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", saveNote, false);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/3vdpT/)

Note: this requires support of [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) which is easily dealt with

Comment: Thanks , but we need to remove also "save" button and add another button something like "edit"

Comment: That is very easy to add to `saveNote` but was not in your original question.

Comment: Yes I know , but we need this
Thanks

Comment: Added your additional requirement.

Comment: All my requirement has been solved but we have an additional requirement for add a "edit" button at place of three button.

Comment: I have not getting any idea how to Added additional requirement ?

Answer (score 11):

`removeNode` seems to be non standard. Try this:

```
if(e && e.nextSibling) {
  e.parentNode.removeChild(e.nextSibling)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I was wanting to do the same thing as this question mentioned but without referencing the parent node. After some googling this is what I found!

It appears as though there is actually a function that will let you do this without referencing the parent node; it is called `remove();`.

Here is a demo.

```js
function removeNextNode(elem) {
  elem.nextElementSibling.remove();
}
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="removeNextNode(this);" href="#">Click to remove the next node...</a>
<a href="#">another node</a>
<a href="#">another node</a>
<a href="#">another node</a>
<a href="#">another node</a>
<a href="#">another node</a>
<a href="#">another node</a>
```

Please post a comment if this answer can be improved.

Comment: It loos like IE does not support it see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `reomveNode` try `removeNode();`.

Comment: Thanks Everyone for spend you valuable time for my issue.
I have coined out a solution

while(e && e.nextSibling) {
    e.parentNode.removeChild(e.nextSibling); 
}
e.parentNode.removeChild(e);